# Is any way to ensure any azure service plan have an unique static outbound IP address in one azure subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-webapps, azure-service-plan

I'm making a distributed crawling system and deploy it in azure.

And I'm using Azure Service Plan as my crawler container.

**This need every Service Plan have a unique static outbound IP address.**

But when I start a Service Plan, it most likely the **new Service Plan's outbound IP address same with another**.

I tried to find out a solution through Azure Document, but unfortunately I can't find a suitable solution.

Any one have solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information on outbound IP Addresses in an App Service Plan, have a look at [Inbound and outbound IP addresses in Azure App Service -Find outbound IPs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-addresses#find-outbound-ips).

> Azure App Service is a multi-tenant service, except for App Service Environments. Apps that are not in an App Service environment (not in the Isolated tier) share network infrastructure with other apps. As a result, the inbound and outbound IP addresses of an app can be different, and can even change in certain situations.

Example:
[image: Finding Outbound IP addresses]

But also:

> **App Service Environments use dedicated network infrastructures, so apps running in an App Service environment get static, dedicated IP addresses both for inbound and outbound connections.**

This means you *can* get static dedicated IP addresses if you use [App Service Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro). This does, of course, incur some extra costs.

Comment: I tried to create a Azure Virtual Network,And then create a App Service Environments, in the App Service Environments, I can create a service plan. but the problem is the App Service Environments is too expensive.